# Get text from an element inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Well I wanted to get the text from a tag element inside an iframe, what I mean is that I would like to click any element inside said iframe and be able to retrieve the text of said tag back to the parent window just like this code does with my current page:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target).text();
});
```

PS: The website contained in the iFrame is not under my control basically I want to web scrape the website but was trying to create a tool to ease the process

Comment: Do you need to pass the text back to the parent window containing the iframe?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be back at the parent window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to communicate between the iframe and parent window, either the content of the iframe has to have been generated by the JavaScript (not sure if it applies if it's an iframe of another file on the same server as well...) Or you have to otherwise have access to the source code of the iframe page, to implement the postMessage API to send data to and from the main page

For example, somewhere in your iframe source code, like on the click of an element, you can call postMessage to send a message to the main frame

```
myButton.onclick= ()=>{
    parent.postMessage({message:"you clicked something"},"*")
}
```

Then in the main file you listen for new messages

```
onmessage = e=> 
    console.log(e.data)
```

Comment: Well this is a great solution, the only issue is that I do not have the control over the website contained in the Iframe, I wanted to create a tool to help a web scrapper to read different tags from a news page, thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @minibozz if you don't have control of the source code of the website then the only ways to do it are 1) make your own browser plugin that can inject script into the iframe or 2) make your own browser, let me know if you want more info

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) and don't worry I guess both solutions are a little bit of an overkill for a thesis project haha

Comment: @minbozz ok lol, as a sightly easier alternative to your own plugin you can use tampermonkey, i think it allows you to inject coffee into iframes, but then whoever's using your code has to have it installed to their browser

Comment: sounds good I'll take a look at it then, thank you very much :)